# problem when i plot 10+ curve on bokeh plotting

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, curve

i'm plotting temperature curve on bokeh plot, and it works when the number of curve is 9 or less.
when i'm trying to plot 10 or more, there is only 1 curve on the bokeh plot and the scale is different than before.
it seems the curve which is plotting is just a little part of the entire curve. I've check the length of data and there is no difference between the 9 and the 10 curves so i can't understand what is the problem

[image]
[image: enter image descrenter image description hereiption here]

here is my code :

def afficher_graphique(source, moyenne_values):

```
output_file("graphique.html")

p = figure(title="Température Rack", x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='T°C_rack', plot_width=1500, plot_height=300)
clim_names = source.data.get('clim_name', [])
renderers = []

color = ['red','blue','black','navy','deepskyblue','green','red','grey','orange','cyan','magenta','red','teal'
          ,'black','purple']

for i, clim_name in enumerate(clim_names):
    column_name = f'Tr_{i + 1}'  # Assurez-vous que le nom de la colonne est correct
    if column_name in source.data:
        line_color = color[i]
        line = p.line('date', column_name, source=source, line_color=line_color)
        renderers.append(line)

p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%d/%m/%y")

legend_items = [(clim_name, [line]) for clim_name, line in zip(clim_names, renderers)]

# Ajoutez les valeurs moyennes à la légende
legend_items_with_values = [(f"{clim_name} ({moyenne_value}°C)", line)
    for (clim_name, line), moyenne_value in zip(legend_items, moyenne_values)]

legend = Legend(items=legend_items_with_values, location="center")
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Value', '$y')])  # Outil permettant d'afficher les infos du graph lorsqu'on le survole
tool_list = [hover]
p.add_tools(*tool_list)

show(p, notebook_handle=True)
```

##################################################################

def run_simulation(pays, batterie, container, chemin_accès_soll, chemin_accès_temp):

```
# Constantes pour les noms de clés
DATE_KEY = "dates"
TEMP_KEY = "temperatures"
CLIM_NAME_KEY = "clim_names"
MOYENNE_KEY = "moyenne_Tr"
MIN_KEY = "minimum_Tr"
MAX_KEY = "maximum_Tr"

dico_general = localisation(pays)

results = {DATE_KEY: [], TEMP_KEY: [], CLIM_NAME_KEY: [], MOYENNE_KEY: [], MIN_KEY: [], MAX_KEY: []}  

for clim in dico_general:
    
    result_clim = main_simu_thermique(.................
```

...........................................................
...........................................................
..........here is my parameters for main_simu_thermique....
..........................................................)

```
    print (len(f"Températures : {result_clim['Tr']}"))
    
    results[DATE_KEY].append(result_clim["date"])
    results[TEMP_KEY].append(result_clim["Tr"])
    results[CLIM_NAME_KEY].append(clim)
    
    moyenne_value = result_clim["Moy_Tr"]
    moyenne_1_decimale = round_values(moyenne_value)
    results[MOYENNE_KEY].append(moyenne_1_decimale)
    print(f"Pour {clim}, la T°C moyenne est : {moyenne_1_decimale}")

    min_value = result_clim["Min_Tr"]
    min_1_decimale = round_values(min_value)
    results[MIN_KEY].append(min_1_decimale)
    print(f"Pour {clim}, la T°C min est : {min_1_decimale}")

    max_value = result_clim["Max_Tr"] 
    max_1_decimale = round_values(max_value)
    results[MAX_KEY].append(max_1_decimale)
    print(f"Pour {clim}, la T°C max est : {max_1_decimale}")
            
return results
```

#########################################################

def simulation(pays, batterie, container, fenetre, chemin_accès_soll, chemin_accès_temp):

```
if fenetre and isinstance(fenetre, Tk):
    fenetre.destroy()

results = run_simulation(pays, batterie, container, chemin_accès_soll, chemin_accès_temp)

source_data = {"date": results["dates"][0]}

for i, temperatures in enumerate(results["temperatures"]):
    source_data[f'Tr_{i + 1}'] = temperatures

source_data["Moy_Tr"] = results["moyenne_Tr"]
source_data["Min_Tr"] = results["minimum_Tr"]
source_data["Max_Tr"] = results["maximum_Tr"]
source_data["clim_name"] = results["clim_names"]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=source_data)
afficher_graphique(source, results["moyenne_Tr"])

check_simulation_data(results)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
dropdown_list()

##################################################################

how can i plot 10+ cruve on bokeh ?

thanks for help

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot

Comment: please post the data and code you are executing

Comment: data are very long (1440 values per column), so i can't post it

Comment: Could you please show the head of the data, maybe 5 values per column?

Comment: here is an example of timedata and temperatures associate : 
Date : [Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:01:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:02:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:03:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:04:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:05:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:06:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:07:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:08:00'), Timestamp('2018-07-28 00:09:00')

Températures : [23.0, 23.000425944046633, 23.001219174992464, 23.00232909111743, 23.00371233781407, 23.005331757056137, 23.007155489437704, 23.00915620686359, 23.01131045685976,

Comment: the simulation runs for 24 hours in 1 minute steps, and here is the len of time and temperature data : 
28255 (len temperature data)
48967(len time data)

Comment: How do you solve the mismatch of the length between time and data? I think the problem is not related to bokeh, it is you data management. I bokeh figure can easily display ten or more lines.
**Example**
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.palettes import BrBG11
output_notebook()
timestamps = pd.date_range('2018-07-28', periods=20, freq='1T')
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (11, 20))
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
for d, c in zip(data, BrBG11):
    p.line(timestamps, d, color=c, legend_label=c)
show(p)`

Comment: i don't no where the mismatch is producing but, spite of this, the plot working for the 9 lines before, so i don't thinks that's the problem